# Google Chrome redirecting router request to port 81

Tags: google-chrome, router, redirection, port-redirection

When I browse to 192.168.0.1, Chrome redirects me to 192.168.0.1:81 and obviously the page doesn't load. Something's gone wonky but I don't know what. The problem doesn't happen in Firefox or IE and didn't start happening until a week ago.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Chrome profile your currently using?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I don't see why that would be what's at fault. I've tested this on another computer which has a different account and it happens as well. FWIW, this all started happening when I flashed the firmware of my router. I thought the router was effed so I bought a new one and the problem is still happening. Did the first router send some bad info to the computers that's persisting through Chrome somehow? I've tried ipconfig /flushdns already - but either way it's specifically through Chrome.

Comment: Can you try wiping the profile?

Comment: Have you tried specifying port 80 in your request in chrome? Have you tried using https instead?

Comment: I've tried specifying port 80, it still redirects. Yes, I can access it via https on the separate port it told me to use. I won't wipe the profile unless it's a last resort. I'll note something else: My modem (Rogers) interface page works on port 80 as well (it's a different IP address though).